# Plotting the distribution of a variable through time - cumulative addition

Tags: r

I am trying to do something quite difficult for my expertise on R.
I have a date variable, which basically states when the respondents of my survey started it. Therefore, there are missing values (non-respondents) and the dates (respondents).

What I want to plot is the frequency distribution of a concrete variable (for example % of Women) through the time frame I have. So, put it simply, a graph that shows for the first day X% of women, the second one (including as well people from first day) Y% and so on; for the three experimental groups available.

I am clueless. I check some resources that use rain or other natural phenomenon as example and uses the

```
cumsum()
```

command inside ggplot to perform it but seems not the way to go for my purpose. I am not even sure if I need another package.

Here is the example data

```
df <- structure(list(sf_sex = c("Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
                      "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
                      "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
                      "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
                      "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
                      "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
                      "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
                      "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
                      "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
                      "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
                      "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
                      "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
                      "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
                      "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
                      "Female"), StartDate = c("06/07/2019", "06/06/2019", NA, "05/21/2019", 
                                               NA, NA, "05/24/2019", NA, NA, "05/20/2019", NA, "06/04/2019", 
                                               NA, NA, NA, NA, "06/16/2019", NA, NA, NA, "05/23/2019", NA, NA, 
                                               NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "05/23/2019", 
                                               NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "05/22/2019", NA, "06/13/2019", 
                                               NA, NA, "05/28/2019", "05/23/2019", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "05/29/2019", 
                                               "05/22/2019", NA, "05/23/2019", NA, "05/31/2019", NA, "05/22/2019", 
                                               NA, "07/02/2019", "06/02/2019", NA, NA, "05/27/2019", NA, NA, 
                                               NA, "05/27/2019", NA, NA, NA, NA, "06/04/2019", "05/22/2019", 
                                               NA, NA, "05/24/2019", NA, "05/25/2019", "05/21/2019", "05/20/2019", 
                                               NA, NA, "05/24/2019", NA, NA, "06/03/2019", "05/22/2019", "05/20/2019"
                      )), row.names = c(2L, 9L, 12L, 23L, 24L, 38L, 48L, 49L, 52L, 
                                        53L, 55L, 68L, 71L, 75L, 84L, 90L, 107L, 114L, 115L, 117L, 118L, 
                                        122L, 125L, 134L, 138L, 144L, 148L, 163L, 169L, 179L, 185L, 188L, 
                                        199L, 206L, 209L, 211L, 223L, 227L, 230L, 233L, 234L, 237L, 241L, 
                                        243L, 247L, 257L, 269L, 275L, 277L, 284L, 287L, 288L, 291L, 292L, 
                                        295L, 301L, 310L, 314L, 316L, 324L, 329L, 331L, 333L, 338L, 341L, 
                                        344L, 363L, 365L, 372L, 373L, 375L, 385L, 400L, 401L, 411L, 416L, 
                                        421L, 423L, 427L, 429L, 439L, 440L, 443L, 444L, 455L, 465L, 468L, 
                                        479L, 504L, 511L, 518L, 522L, 528L, 529L, 530L, 538L, 541L, 542L, 
                                        543L, 554L), class = "data.frame")
```

And NA cases should be ignored as this were people that did not participate.

Sorry if the data occupies too much space and thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a well formulated question!

Here's my solution, with comments to explain a bit -- let me know if anything isn't clear.

```
df %>% 
  # convert StartDate from character to something sort-able 
  mutate(date = lubridate::mdy(StartDate)) %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  # get numerator and denominator of proportion female by date x
  mutate(Rs = cumsum(sf_sex %in% c("Male", "Female")),
         female_Rs = cumsum(sf_sex == "Female")) %>% 
  # take last observation per date
  group_by(date) %>% 
  slice(n()) %>% 
  select(date, Rs, female_Rs) %>% 
  # make the proportion
  mutate(female_prop = female_Rs/Rs) %>% 
  # plot it over time
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = female_prop)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: You would need a `group_by` step before doing the `cumsum`s. I wonder if you should post a new question, with the data including the group indicator.

Answer (score 2):

#Update

```
df %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  mutate(StartDate = as.Date(StartDate, format = "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  group_by(sf_sex, StartDate) %>%
  summarise(cnt = n(), .groups = "drop") %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(StartDate) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = sf_sex, values_from = cnt, values_fill = 0) %>%
  mutate(Female_cum_prop = cumsum(Female) / cumsum(Female + Male)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = StartDate, y = Female_cum_prop)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

which gives

[image]

---

Do you mean something like below?

```
df %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  mutate(cnt = 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = StartDate, y = cnt, fill = sf_sex)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack")
```

[image]

or

```
df %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  mutate(cnt = 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = StartDate, y = cnt, fill = sf_sex)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! The problem is that the graphs are not cumulative and just taking into consideration the day exlusively right?

Comment: @MarcAsensioManjon Sorry, my bad. Seems I didn't fully get your point in the question. Now I updated my answer. Hope it helps.